# Не верный формат даты java.sql.Date и java.util.Date

Tags: java, дата

Мне нужно чтобы в хранимую процедуру подавалась текущая дата

потом она парсится в формате

```
public static String format(Date sqlDate ) {
        String DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
        if (date == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return FastDateFormat.getInstance(DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN).format(sqlDate );
    }
```

date я получаю так

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new Date();
String stringDate = dateFormat.format(utilDate);
 try {
   date = dateFormat.parse(stringDate);
   } catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
 java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
```

в итоге мне приходит на вход метода format дата в таком виде

2018-12-18T12:46:34.000+0300

и падает ошибка

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/time/FastDateFormat

Comment: Ну и в чем проблема? Сложно подстроить паттерн под нужный вид?

Comment: паттерн у меня такой же стоит, но он почему то не отрабатывает.

Comment: private final String DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";                      
    private final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_PATTERN);

Comment: Невооруженным глазом видно, что не такой же.